# How would you use jQuery autocomplete with a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

I want to use terms that are stored in a table called terms with id and term columns

How could I use autocomplete with a database instead of an array?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<input id="autocomplete" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get array with ajax call or initialize at page load something like

```
<script>
var myArr = [<?php foreach($dbRows as $row){ echo "\"$row['keyword']\","} ?>];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways how you can connect to the database. What both have in common is that you need PHP (or another language) in between which will connect to the database and prepare the results for autocomplete.

The first way is how Headshota described it. In this solution PHP is filling the autocomplete words already into the HTML page.

The second solution is when autocomplete is making another request to the server and then downloads the list of words. On the [autocomplete demo page](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/) you will find at the bottom a link to a PHP source file. And within the HTML code of the demo page you will find under "Single Bird (remote)" how you have to write the HTML/JavaScript code.

Which way you will choose is mostly based on the number of rows in your table. If you have several hundred rows then I would go for the second solution. For less data the first solution is OK too.